# Mysql - How to use field data as POINT() function

Tags: mysql, sql, point

I have a sql like this:

```
SELECT
  userAddress.user_address_complete,
  userAddress.user_address_point,
  deliveryZone.delivery_zone_id,
  St_contains(deliveryZone.delivery_zone_polygon,
  Geomfromtext('POINT(userAddress.user_address_point)')) AS cnt
FROM user_addresses userAddress
LEFT JOIN delivery_zones deliveryZone
  ON (deliveryZone.restaurants_id = 154
  AND St_contains(deliveryZone.delivery_zone_polygon,
  Geomfromtext('POINT(userAddress.user_address_point)'))
  > 0)
WHERE userAddress.user_address_user_id = 1
```

problem is that `POINT(userAddress.user_address_point)` should use `userAddress.user_address_point` field data, but sql can't understand that it is a field name and behave with it like a string so we have not result.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude column name from string. Split it into
    `'POINT('userAddress.user_address_point'))`

```
SELECT
  userAddress.user_address_complete,
  userAddress.user_address_point,
  deliveryZone.delivery_zone_id,
  St_contains(deliveryZone.delivery_zone_polygon,
  Geomfromtext('POINT('userAddress.user_address_point')')) AS cnt
FROM user_addresses userAddress
LEFT JOIN delivery_zones deliveryZone
  ON (deliveryZone.restaurants_id = 154
  AND St_contains(deliveryZone.delivery_zone_polygon,
  Geomfromtext('POINT('userAddress.user_address_point')'))
  > 0)
WHERE userAddress.user_address_user_id = 1
```

Comment: I give an error : Use of undefined constant UserAddress - assumed 'UserAddress'. I guess it's not necessary way to do this beacause UserAddress is one of my entity and it can't define as constant variable.

Comment: Ok, I thought UserAddress is a PHP Model. Try to replace `\'POINT(UserAddress.userAddressPoint)\'` to `POINT(UserAddress.userAddressPoint)`

Comment: I changed my question , please review it again.